# How do you make an Arraylist of RandomNumber integers? java

Tags: java, bluej

So I am relatively new to the programming scene and I am confused as to why my code doesn't work. I am trying to make an `arraylist` of flowers and then use a random number generator to create a random number of certain flowers, and store them in the array. In my logic, I thought that I created a variable to store the numbers (ex `randomRoses`) and stored the number in the array so I could easily print out how many of each flower there is by just calling the `arraylist` and the position. (ex `flowerArray[0]` would print out 8 Roses) but sadly it does not.

```
public class Flower
{

    private int randomRoses;
    private int randomTulips;
    private int randomOrchids;
    public ArrayList <Integer> flowerArray;

    public Flower()
    {
        r = new Random();
        t = new Random();
        o = new Random();
        int randomRoses = (r.nextInt(10) + 0);
        int randomTulips = (t.nextInt(10) + 0);
        int randomOrchids = (o.nextInt(10) + 0);
        flowerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>
    }

    public void add2Array ()
    {
        flowerArray.add(randomRoses); //flowerArray[0] is the # of roses
        flowerArray.add(randomTulips); //flowerArray[1] is the # of tulips
        flowerArray.add(randomOrchids); //flowerArray[2] is the # of orchids
    }

    public void printArray()
    {
        System.out.println(flowerArray[0]);
    }
```

Comment: You should first generate random numbers and add them to a set until its size is 3 and then do other things by converting that set to another container if necessary

Comment: Also , `r.nextInt(10) + 0` ==> No need of adding `0` here

Comment: How is it supposed to print Roses?

Comment: Your code does not compile like this. There is problems with the scope of your variables

Comment: Sorry guys, I was copying my code from another computer so I forgot to add the r, t, and o in the fields.

Comment: @LynnLove - You are still missing the important point. All your flowers could end up having the same random number (in your current code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same random object, no need to create 3 instances of it for the random integer generation,

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    flowerArray.add(r.nextInt(10));
}
System.out.println(flowerArray);
```

you can not do `flowerArray[0]` **because you have an arrayList and not an array.**
you can instead do: `flowerArray.get(0)` for getting the integer at pos zero

Comment: Thank you for distinguishing the difference. I had no idea. Very helpful :)

Comment: I honestly don't think that this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here your array list is associated with a class object. When you initialize your array list you need to add your entries to the array list in the constructor itself. So when you say object.printArray() its actually returning you the empty array list, that's why you are getting 0 every time. Try This.

```
class Flower
{
    private int randomRoses;
    private int randomTulips;
    private int randomOrchids;
    public ArrayList<Integer> flowerArray;
    public Flower()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Random t = new Random();
        Random o = new Random();
        int randomRoses = (r.nextInt(10));
        int randomTulips = (t.nextInt(10));
        int randomOrchids = (o.nextInt(10));
        System.out.println(randomRoses);
        System.out.println(randomTulips);
        System.out.println(randomOrchids);
        flowerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        flowerArray.add(randomRoses); //flowerArray[0] is the # of roses
        flowerArray.add(randomTulips); //flowerArray[1] is the # of tulips
        flowerArray.add(randomOrchids); //flowerArray[2] is the # of orchids
    }
    public void printArray()
    {
        System.out.println(flowerArray.get(0));
    }
}
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Flower f = new Flower();
       f.printArray();
    }
}
```

And in array list you can get elements by using **get(index)** method.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the output you expect.

```
public void printArray
{
 System.out.println(flowerArray.get(0)+" Roses");
System.out.println(flowerArray.get(1)+" Tulips");
System.out.println(flowerArray.get(2)+" Orchids");

}
```

Also you missed a semi-colon after the statement defining the arraylist. 
Make the correction:

```
flowerArray=new ArrayList<Integer>;
```

How did it compile without that semi-colon?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because your syntax for getting the ith flower is wrong. 
You're using a java.util.ArrayList so the correct way to get an object from that ArrayList is by calling the get() method.

```
System.out.println(flowerArray.get(0));
```

Hope that helps.